# Missing top solder mask complaint when trying to order PCB? (PCBWay)

Tags: pcb-design, eaglecad, pcb-fabrication, pcb-layers, solder-mask

I'm really new to PCB layout and after creating my PCB layout and ordering it from PCB Way my audit was failed for reason "no top solder mask layer." What does that mean and how would I add that? If it helps here are my schematic and board design. Also in my zip file I had the .cmp file, .drd file, .dri file, .drl file, .gpi file, .plc file, .sol file, and .stc file.

[image: Board Design]

[image: Schematic]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Solder mask is the shiny laquer that is applied to the top and bottom of the PCB at the end of manufacture but before soldering components.  Typically it is generated automatically by the EDA software (Eagle, in your case) based on the package geometry of all your parts.  I am not familiar with Eagle, but normally you can fix this in the Layer Manager (or equvalent) dialog.  Add the top and bottom solder masks and re-generate your Gerber package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Soldermask, also called solder resist, is the coating that you see on most professional PCBs, most commonly in green. It is used to keep solder off of copper that you don't want solder on (such as the tracks themselves). Generally it is a sheet with holes cut out slightly larger than the pads they encompass. This allows the assembler to solder to the copper pads (the solder mask has an opening around these pads) but the solder will not wick down the trace.

[image]

Eagle calls its top soldermask layer tStop and its bottom soldermask layer bStop. In order for the manufacturer to fabricate these boards, they need to have both. This means that when you export the Gerber files, you need to make sure the tStop and bStop files are included and are sent to the manufacturer.

Comment: Ok thanks! How would I get the files for just the tStop and bStop? Sorry again I am really new to Eagle layout and I cant seem to find out how online.

Comment: You can follow the instructions here to generate the Gerber files from your Eagle project: http://www.build-electronic-circuits.com/gerber-file/ . Generally you would generate all gerber files at once and send them in a ZIP file to your manufacturer

Comment: It's also good to include a readme.txt file describing the stack up (if a multilayer board) and which layer each file represents, because the filenames can be ambiguous sometimes.

Comment: Excellent addition @pericynthion

Answer (score 0):

Top solder mask layer is for PRINT color ink on the boards.I think you could put on solder layers IF you use eagle.
short name is: .GTS file

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. What is "PRINT color ink"? What does "put on solder layers" mean?

Comment: i mean the solder mask layer is for print the ink on the boards